# Does Vitali's convergence Theorem apply in $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I am trying to understand if I can apply Vitali's convergence Theorem for the set $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^N$. As far as I know, the Theorem holds when ${\rm meas}(\Omega)<+\infty$, so my question is: is $\mathbb{R}^N$ a finite measure set?

(About me, the answer is no).

Anyway, if not, there exists some Theorem for passing to the limit under the integral for unbounded set?

I am sorry for the possibly dumb question. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: $\mathbb R^N$ is not a finite measure space (wrt lebesque measure). Vitalli's convergence theorem is valid for finite measure spaces. However, you can extend the definition of uniform integrability so that vitallis theorem can be extended to infinite measure spaces. In   [this](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110532982/html) book,   the authors give a different definition of uniform integrability (Definition 2.3.40), so that Vitallis thm (Theorem 2.3.44) holds for general measure spaces

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. it seems a nice reference, thank you. I am not able to grasp right now the difference between the classical definition of uniform integrability and the one in the book. If you do (and if you want), could you please exlpain it to me?

Comment: well, the classic definition of u.i. is usually something like: a family $\mathcal F \subset L^1$ is called u.i. if $ \sup_{f \in \mathcal F} \int_{|f| \geq c} |f| \to 0$ as $c \to \infty$. The authors also require that for every $ε>0$, there eixsts  a finite measure set $D_ε$  such that $\sup_{f \in \mathcal F} \int_{ X \setminus D_ε} |f| \leq ε $. This extra condition is useful for using theorems that require finite measure (egorov thm for instance); see the proof of vitalli's thm.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Thank you very much!